# use of spec sensor in arduino uno

Tags: sensors

i have been trying to use NO2 spec senor in arduino UNO. how to write the code for it to get the output in terms of 'ppm' and how to give connection.with the helo of cross-sensitivity given in datasheet how to detect the interference gases from this sensor itself..the datasheet URL:

https://www.spec-sensors.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/3SP_NO2_5F-C-Package-110-508.pdf

Comment: Have you considered the sensor requires additional hardware to interface with an embedded processor?  The [development kit sold for this sensor costs about $350](https://www.spec-sensors.com/product/digital-gas-sensor-developer-kit/).  While you may be able to build your own for a fraction of the price, I doubt you will be able to use this sensor with only a stock Arduino and some code.

Answer (score 2):

In the specification sheet linked to in the post we find this:

> -30+/-10nA/ppm

This is a very small amount of current.  The Arduino ADC is a voltage sensing device and (unless modified) has a range of 0 to the operating voltage of the Arduino.  Usually 3.3V or 5V.

Converting nano Amps to that range of voltage will require additional hardware.  A stock Arduino and code are unlikely to make use of such a sensor.

The conversion of such small amounts of current to voltages measurable by a stock Arduino is not trivial. And most answers do not fit into the short format of stack exchange.  [Here is an Engineering Design News article](https://www.edn.com/design/analog/4315417/Measuring-nanoamperes) on the subject.